# Funções definidas dentro de blocos condicionais

Tags: php, funções, if

Estou estudando o PHP e lendo a documentação me deparei com este exemplo:

```
<?php

$makefoo = true;

/* Nos nao podemos chamar foo() daqui
   porque ela ainda não existe,
   mas nos podemos chamar bar() */

bar();

if ($makefoo) {
  function foo()
  {
    echo "Eu não existo até que o programa passe por aqui.\n";
  }
}

/* Agora nos podemos chamar foo()
   porque $makefoo foi avaliado como true */

if ($makefoo) foo();

function bar()
{
  echo "Eu existo imediatamente desde o programa começar.\n";
}

?>
```

Eu entendi que a função só passará a existir se a condição for avaliada como verdadeira, mas me abriu algumas dúvidas, por que o que acredito ser normal (pelo que vejo em *scripts* de terceiros) é definir funções e decidir qual irá invocar a partir de testes condicionais, mas nesse exemplo da documentação o teste irá definir se a função será declarada ou não, impedindo que a mesma seja invocada posteriormente em caso negativo, o que me leva a algumas dúvidas:

É considerada uma boa prática? Visto que o código acredito eu se torna mais complexo, pois o restante do meu código deve estar preparado para funcionar perfeitamente mesmo com a ausência dessa função.

Teria algum exemplo de aplicação? Sou do tipo que entende mais claramente as coisas com algum exemplo.

Comment: Eu particularmente não vejo qualquer motivo para chamar uma função antes dela estar definida. Ao meu ver é contra-intuitivo e o código deveria ser intuitivo. Aliás, o que deveria ser `bar` no seu exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra quem me acompanha sabe que sou crítico de boas práticas, e claro, as más também. Gosto de entender motivações, ter o fundamento para fazer certo. E falo muito de contexto. Tudo pode ser válido no contexto certo. E pode ser que o contexto válido é um sem sentido.

A pergunta não mostra a referência para dar contexto porque o código foi feito assim. Pode ter um motivo. E quem fez normalmente deveria justificar. Em programação devemos fazer só o que podemos justificar. Não podemos fazer porque alguém fez antes, tem que ser sempre porque precisa. E não pode ser justificativa inventada, forçada, tem que ser um uso justo mesmo.

Que problema isso tenta resolver? Eu não consigo ver um motivo para isso. Então se quem usa não puder mostrar a vantagem não é boa prática.

Eu suspeito, e só suspeito mesmo que pode ser uma otimização por ser uma linguagem interpretada, e tola, até porque se a linguagem precisa disto e você se beneficia fundamentalmente por fazer assim ela é a ferramenta errada. E tem casos que será pior, principalmente se estiver usando alguma ferramenta que faça cache do código compilado.

Também poderia ser programação defensiva, mas do jeito errado. O código está tentando resolver um possível problema, mas isso é erro de programação, e erro de programação a gente conserta no código e não tenta contornar na execução.

Por fim pode ser algum "truque esperto", o que se chama *clever code* para conseguir fazer algumas coisa muito flexível, mas me parece gambiarra. Pode ser uma forma de criar um *template*, mas dessa forma eu nunca usaria.

Se pelo menos a função tivesse escopo local, mas terá escopo global igual as outras.

De fato o código se torna complexo e não dá para ver vantagem. Na verdade considero um erro da linguagem permitir este tipo de coisa.

Crie as funções que precisa e decida em algum momento se deve chamá-las, mas não a definição. Declarações e definições nunca deveriam ser condicionais.

Comment: Lendo a documentação e do nada te jogam essa forma de se definir funções, pensei `"Nossa nunca tinha visto, mas onde usaria?`

Comment: É como você disse: `"Dependendo do contexto, tudo pode ser válido"`.